# SQL query with relationship and column compare

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do the following with an SQL (Postgres) statement:

**Select all yards where equipments.yard_id = yard.id and equipments. equipment_type_id = 3,4,6 and equipments.quantity (equipment_type_id = 6) is greater than total quantity of equipment_type_id 3 & 4**

```
Yards:
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Yard 1 |
|  2 | Yard 2 |
|  3 | Yard 3 |
+----+--------+

Equipments:

+----+---------+-------------------+----------+
| id | yard_id | equipment_type_id | quantity |
+----+---------+-------------------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |                 3 |        4 |
|  2 |       2 |                 3 |        5 |
|  3 |       1 |                 6 |        4 |
|  4 |       2 |                 4 |        2 |
|  5 |       2 |                 6 |        2 |
+----+---------+-------------------+----------+
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yards y
  JOIN equipments e
    ON e.yard_id=y.id AND e.equipment_type_id=3 OR e.equipment_type_id=4 AND e.equipment_type_id=6
```

Which currently returns all the Yards that have equipment_type_id 3 or 4 and 6. I need to adjust this so I return all Yards where the sum of equipment_type_id = 6 is greater than the sum of 3 & 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what's the best way to provide sample data?

Comment: @GordonLinoff have updated my question, hopefully it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon for the help, I have adjusted his query to work for an older version of Postgres:

```
SELECT y.name
FROM yards y JOIN
     equipments e
     ON e.yard_id = y.id AND e.equipment_type_id IN (3, 4, 6) 
GROUP BY y.name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.equipment_type_id IN (6) THEN quantity END) > SUM(CASE WHEN e.equipment_type_id IN (3,4) THEN quantity END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, this needs aggregation.  The final condition is a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT y.id
FROM yards y JOIN
     equipments e
     ON e.yard_id = y.id AND e.equipment_type_id IN (3, 4, 6) 
GROUP BY y.id
HAVING (SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE e.equipment_type IN (6)) >
        SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE e.equipment_type IN (3, 4))
       );
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, unfortunately the version of Postgres I am using doesn't have the FITLER clause, from reading CASE WHEN should be used but I can't get this working. Any ideas how I can replace the above using CASE WHEN?

Comment: Then just use `SUM(CASE . . . END)`.